# Importing proxy configuration from WinSCP to IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, sftp, jetbrains-ide, winscp

I would like to use IntelliJ to configure my SFTP servers.

Unfortunately, I have very complex configurations (SSH tunnels, proxy etc...) that I am currently doing with WinSCP.

Is it possible to import the exported WinSCP configurations into IntelliJ?
If not, what is the procedure to configure in IntelliJ an SFTP connection in WinSCP with

- SSH Tunnel with private key
- Proxy server

I have tried to set SSH and proxy with the settings I've found in IntelliJ, but it gives me connection timeout.

Comment: Are _"settings I've found in IntelliJ"_ the [HTTP Proxy settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-http-proxy.html) and the [Remote server configuration settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html)?

Comment: Yes, of course they are

Comment: Have you tried any plugin such as **FTP/SFTP Connectivity ​(ex.​ Remote Hosts Access)​**?

Comment: Why would you like to use IntelliJ Idea to configure your `SFTP` servers?  This is wrong tool for such task.  Could you elaborate the details, why you need it this way?  What are you trying to achive?

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ is not made for SFTP and other connection maintenance. You can easily import export from FileZilla to WinSCP and other SFTP IDE. IntelliJ is more like code editor for multiple platforms and it has little FTP file window program but it cannot have all settings like WinSCP has.

But if you still want to do it.
You have to find `webserver.xml` file or create a manual entry first time. It will create a file then edit that file. Check the format of your first manual entry.
I think password is encrypted. Learn how to encrypt password and write in xml file.
Passwords are now stored in either KeePass file (all platforms) or keychain (Mac & Linux; where supported libs are present).
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207074025-webServers-xml-format#5275025